# Resizing Trello lists bug with Internet Explorer

Tags: trello, trello-lists, internet-explorer

Some of my team use Firefox, some use Internet Explorer.

The guys on IE have a problem where by if they scroll down a long vertical list, then hover over a card - the list resizes and jumps back up the page?

Any way around this? (Other than using Firefox where it seems to be OK.)

Answer (score 1):

For these cases you should always consider indicating:

- Each operating system and its version
- Each browser and its version

Once you have gathered this informarion check Trello support for those platforms at [trello help](http://help.trello.com/article/735-what-browsers-and-mobile-platforms-does-trello-support)

If everything should be fine, try to reproduce the problem in other computers having the same platforms.

If still if you have problems, consider requiring support to Trello team by their contact form.